# UBUNTU GNOME 16.10 constantly asked to enter password for keyring

Tags: 16.10, ubuntu-gnome, keyrings

I have just installed ubuntu 16.10, have all the latest updates and keep getting asked to decrypt a keyring. I have never seen this ever and I have been using ubuntu gnome for two years.

I started with a completely new user account.

Why am I always being asked this? It happens when I try and start software, install software, authorise online accounts etc... and I enter my password for the current user but it doesn't seem to be the required password. I keep getting asked over and over again

Comment: Are you sure this isn't when you're using the Chrome browser?  It's notorious for asking for that repeatedly.  Usually, entering a blank password make it go away.

Comment: Yes, and I use chrome as my main browser ever since using linux. I have never been asked this before - ever. Now it is happening all the time. As I don't know what password it want's I have no Idea how to stop it appearing.